# Software that can print correct temperature for AMD Ryzen 2990WX

Tags: linux, open-source, ubuntu, monitoring

Recently I got a machine with an AMD Ryzen 2990WX CPU and `sensors` from `lm-sensors` seems to give me wrong temperature to me.

Its output looks like

```
iwlwifi-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:            N/A  

k10temp-pci-00d3
Adapter: PCI adapter
Tdie:         +62.5°C  (high = +70.0°C)
Tctl:         +89.5°C  

k10temp-pci-00c3
Adapter: PCI adapter
Tdie:         +62.8°C  (high = +70.0°C)
Tctl:         +89.8°C  

k10temp-pci-00db
Adapter: PCI adapter
Tdie:         +58.5°C  (high = +70.0°C)
Tctl:         +85.5°C  

k10temp-pci-00cb
Adapter: PCI adapter
Tdie:         +61.8°C  (high = +70.0°C)
Tctl:         +88.8°C
```

And I found from the community that the kernel does not support it yet. Is there any software with which I can check the correct temperature of my CPU?